# Android text change is causing the rest of the screen not to load

Tags: android

I am trying to change text when an action occurs using:

```
final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerTextHeader);

textViewToChange.setText("Error getting seed! (" + message + ") TEXT HERE NOT SHOWING");
```

message is a String. However when ever this change is triggered I get:

"Error getting seed! (ERR1"

When I expect to get:

"Error getting seed! (ERR1) TEXT HERE NOT SHOWING"

---

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/registerTextHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/registration_header" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userPassword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerSubmitButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the type of message variable?

Comment: Check TextView properties in your xml file and make sure that you are not restricting the ability of the TextView to grow.

Comment: Added the layout xml to the question.

Comment: @dmaxi The message variable is a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem... the String message was 1024 bytes long and contained padding causing the problems.